# Stored procedure dynamic where clause, getting a value from a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using sql server, c#, asp.net. I am doing a project where menus are dynamically displayed from the database according to user's permission. As of now here's my stored procedure,

```
Create Proc spGetMenuData
as
Begin
 Select * from tblMenu1
End
```

I have a users table, a roles table and menu table on my database.
Users: userid, username, pass, roleid
Roles: roleid, name (admin, user)
Menu: menuid, name, url, roleid, userid OR menuid, name, url, roleid (please tell me too if what's more appropriate)
Now, what I want is to get the userid and his roleid to check for the menus. I can store the userid to a variable from my program and pass it to my stored procedure.
Like:

```
Create Proc spGetMenuData
as
Begin
 Select * from tblMenu1 //(WHERE tblMenu1.userid = useridfromthevariable and tblMenu1.roleid = useridfromthevariable's roleid)
End
```

Please help me, I'm just a beginner.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: try creating table for usersmenu instead of relying in MENU as your many is to many table?

Comment: It's tblMenu1 not menu, sorry. That's my usersmenu.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do: 
Users table: user_id, username, pass, role_id 
Roles table: role_id, role_name 
Menu_Roles table: role_id, menu_id 
Menus table: menu_id, name, url 
I would then specify that menus belong to a role and have roles that belong to users. 
Then to get the menu_id, name, and url for a given user:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getMenus
    @someUserName
AS 

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT menu_id, name, url FROM menus WHERE menu_id 
    IN (select menu_id from users
 JOIN menu_roles ON users.role_id=menu_roles.role_id WHERE username=@someUserName)
GO
```

Comment: How can I execute the @someuserName variable to the stored procedure? And you can't select the menu_id from users

Comment: You pass it into the stored procedure from your C# application. At the beginning of the stored procedure you then declare it such as @someUsername VARCHAR(100). You are also correct, menu_id is not in users, that should have read role_id. I'll edit it.

Comment: Would you recommend me to do simple commands rather than stored procedures?

Comment: It's easy for maintenance if you use stored procedures. If your application changes dramatically you have all your database code in one place. However, I currently work as a .NET developer and if I can get away with just putting queries into my application code I will do that. I would create a separate class to put all my database related code in though, say dbHelper.cs. I then call on the various functions of the dbHelper class to retrieve the data. That way if I do need to change my DB code, I can find it all in the dbHelper class.

Comment: Please include in your answer the stored procedure that you would use. Please have it complete. Sorry, I'm just a newbie. :( If it worked, I'll accept  your answer.

Comment: the @soneuserName above is where I should declare it, right?

Comment: Yes, in the stored procedure. Note that this has nothing to do with declaring it in your application. The two are completely separate.

Comment: Woot! That would be my problem, how could I ba eable to pass the variable from my project?

Comment: That's well beyond the scope of this question. There are plenty of resources on the web at how to communicate with SQL Server through a .NET Application. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.110).aspx#_SqlClient

Comment: SELECT * FROM tblMenu WHERE menuID in (select menuID from tblMenuRoles JOIN tblUser ON tblMenuRoles.roleID=tblUser.roleID where username like '" + lblWelcome.Text + "' here's the correct query